# Summation of reciprocal of Product of Factorials.

Tags: summation, factorial

How can this summation be evaluated:
$${∑ {1\over {a_1!a_2!....a_m!}}}$$

Where $$a_1+a_2+.....+a_m=n$$
Also $a_i !=n $ and $m<n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum\frac{n!}{\prod_ia_i!}=\sum\frac{n!}{\prod_ia_i!}\prod_ix_i^{a_i}$ with $x_i=1$;

hence $\sum\frac{n!}{\prod_ia_i!}=(\sum_i x_i)^{a_1+\ldots+a_m}=m^n$.

Finally, the result is $m^n/n!$.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more,with an example maybe.

Comment: When you expand $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m)^n$, you will find that the coefficient of $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\ldots x_m^{a_m}$ is just $\frac{n!}{a_1!\ldots a_m!}$ with $\sum a_i=n$

Comment: Ok!The multinomial theorem.